# NTP can't sync with servers?

Tags: 14.04, ntp

I am fairly new to NTP an Linux in general, but here is the question ;)

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and then tried to install NTP, but when I use `tail -f /var/log/syslog` I get the following:

```
May 12 12:34:20 x-x-x-x ntpd[8779]: proto: precision = 0.121 usec
May 12 12:34:20 x-x-x-x ntpd[8779]: ntp_io: estimated max descriptors: 1024, initial socket boundary: 16
May 12 12:34:20 x-x-x-x ntpd[8779]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0 UDP 123
May 12 12:34:20 x-x-x-x ntpd[8779]: Listen and drop on 1 v6wildcard :: UDP 123
May 12 12:34:20 x-x-x-x ntpd[8779]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1 UDP 123
May 12 12:34:20 x-x-x-x ntpd[8779]: Listen normally on 3 eth0 x-x-x-x UDP 123
May 12 12:34:20 x-x-x-x ntpd[8779]: Listen normally on 4 lo ::1 UDP 123
May 12 12:34:20 x-x-x-x ntpd[8779]: Listen normally on 5 eth0 (ipv6 address) UDP 123
May 12 12:34:20 x-x-x-x ntpd[8779]: peers refreshed
May 12 12:34:20 x-x-x-x ntpd[8779]: Listening on routing socket on fd #22 for interface updates
```

I replaced the ip addresses for x-x-x-x for security purposes.

What could be the problem? Firewall should be good checked that and even with all ports open I still get the above.

When doing `ntpdc -c sysinfo` I get the right time, but according to this tutorial: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=862620 I should get the message `Jul 17 16:50:22 hostname ntpd[22402]: synchronized to 140.221.9.20, stratum 2` (or somthing similar), but I never get this message? SO is the above output correct or not? Or is there some kind of error?

Comment: your question looks incomplete. what exactly are you trying to achieve? Is it that your clients are not syncing the time from ntp server ? what is the output for referencing time when you issue `ntpdc -c sysinfo` ? if the given time is correct then please update about your goals to post this question.

Comment: Just did, please feal free to ask anything what is not clear enough

Comment: This is not an error. `Jul 17 16:50:22 hostname ntpd[22402]: synchronized to 140.221.9.20, stratum 2` this code is basically a snippet of the log file. **July 17 blah blah** is the time when the author copied the log file snippet from syslog. Only thing you should care about is weather your server makes the dns queries to the ntp server you mentioned in your ntp.conf or not ? in the code you pasted above if you noticed it says startum2, which is another ntp server mentioned in the post. Check your log file and while you restart the ntp daemon

Comment: Ok did that and I assume that the log files are in /var/log/ntpstats/?

Comment: that tutorial is pretty old. Given the comments you'll see in a standard `/etc/ntp.conf` file, I wouldn't trust anything earlier than 2012-02-08` ( I'm new too, to ntp, so take with a grain of salt ;-) )